# Finding a homotopy equivalence between the letters $X$ and $Y$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm trying to show that the letters $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent but I'm having some trouble.

If I let $f$ map three half open prongs of the $X$ into the $Y$ and the last closed prong into the center of the $Y$, and let $g$ map three half open prongs of the $Y$ into the half open prongs of the $X$ with the center of the $Y$ being mapped to the center of the $X$, what would be a homotopy between $g \circ f$ and $Id_{X}$ and a homotopy between $f \circ g$ and $Id_{Y}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have concrete spaces to work with, let $X = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x| \leq 1 \text{ and } y=\pm x \}$ as a subspace of the plane. This is just the superposition of the graphs of the lines $y = \pm x$ restricted to the interval $[-1,1]$. Let us consider $Y = X \setminus \{ (x,-x) : x > 0 \}$ as a subspace of $X$ (this is just $X$ with the lower right leg removed). We have the inclusion $i: Y \to X$. The other way around, we have a map (called a retraction) $r:X \to Y$ defined by
$$ r(x,y) = \begin{cases}(x,y) & \text{if } (x,y) \in Y \\ (0,0) &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$

The idea is that $r$ pushes the lower right leg of $X$ into the center of the figure. However, it does so in one fell swoop. In order to turn this into a continuous motion, which slowly pushes the lower right leg into $X$, we need to provide homotopies. We have $ri = 1_Y$ directly, so the constant homotopy suffices. However it is not true that $ir = 1_X$, because points in the lower right leg are mapped to the center and never return to their original position. We may construct a homotopy $ir \simeq_h 1_X$ as follows: $h:X \times I \to X$ is defined by $$h((x,y),t) = \begin{cases}(x,y) & \text{if } (x,y) \in Y \\ t(x,y) &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$
This homotopy starts at $ir$ and ends at the identity $1_X$. Therefore we have shown that $X$ and $Y$ have the same homotopy type. (Provided we check that all the given maps are continuous, which I'll leave to you as an exercise. One uses the pasting lemma to justify the continuity of piecewise-defined maps such as $h$.)

---

Note that it would be even easier, or at least more satisfying, to just show that both spaces are *contractible*, i.e., homotopy equivalent to a point. To do so, we may use the same kind of argument, by showing that the inclusion of the center point and the retraction of both figures to the center point are homotopy inverses. In this case the homotopy from $ir$ to $1_X$ or $1_Y$ takes the simple form $h((x,y),t) = t(x,y)$, and this works for both $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: "homotopic to a point"->"homotopy equivalent to a point"

"Homotopic" is an adjective describing maps and not spaces.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Of course, thank you.

Comment: Alex, wonderful answer, but just a quick question:  How did you go about finding the homotopy?  As in what was your thought process?  That's the particular skill I'm trying to develop with this question.

Comment: @OliverG A homotopy is a continuous deformation of a map into another. The simplest homotopies to write down are "straight-line" homotopies $h:X \times I \to Y$ of the form $h(x,t) = (1-t)f(x) + tg(x)$. This deforms $f:X \to Y$ into $g:X \to Y$, provided that $Y$ is endowed with some linear structure (in this example, we are dealing with starshaped subsets of Euclidean space, so this works). One will very often attempt to construct homotopies using a combination of these straight-line homotopies, rescaling of the time interval, concatenation of homotopies, gluing piecewise homotopies, etc.

Comment: In this case, I wanted to continuously deform $ir$ into $1_X$. Since the behaviour of $ir$ vastly differs depending on whether its argument belongs to $Y$ or not, I opted to construct a piecewise homotopy by gluing a constant homotopy on $Y$ (as $ir = 1_X$ there) with the straight-line homotopy connecting the constant map $0$ to the identity $1_X$ on $X \setminus Y$.

Comment: Just to be clear:  By constant homotopy you mean $H_1((x,y),t) = (x,y)$ for $(x,y) \in Y$ and by straight-line you mean $H_2((x,y),t) = t(x,y)$ for $(x,y) \in (X - Y) \cup (0,0)$?  And you created $H((x,y),t)$ by the pasting lemma?

Comment: @OliverG Yes. Note that both formulas are special cases of the general straight-line homotopy formula $(1-t)f(x) + t g(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify a bit the situation by supposing that the letter $Y$ is a subspace of $X$. Then you get a first natural map $g:Y\to X$ which is just the inclusion.

So now, you need to push the "right leg" of $X$ to the center. Let $f:X\to Y$ be that map, such as $f|_Y$ is just the identity.

To conclude, you first need to prove that $f\circ g : Y\to X\to Y$ is homotopic to identity of $Y$, but that's clear since $f|_Y$ is the identity. Secondly you need $g\circ f : X\to Y \to X$ to be homotopic to the identity of $X$.

That's not very difficult. Basically you need to see why this homotopy is quite the same as the one which transport the path $\gamma(t)=t$ to $\delta(t) =0$.

Comment: But what is the actual homotopy between $f \circ g$ and $Id_Y$ and $g \circ f$ and $Id_X$?

Comment: For $f\circ g$ it's just $H(t,x)=x$, because $f\circ g$ is already the identity.

For $g\circ f$ it depends how much "troubles" you want, i.e. how much detailed you want you homotopy to be.

Comment: What about for $g \circ f$ and $Id_X$ since any point in the last prong of $X$ won't be mapped back to itself?

Comment: You don't need that $g\circ f = {\rm id}$, but only that these maps are homotopic. It's really the same problem as showing a homotopy equivalence between $[0,1]$ and $\{0\}$.

Comment: So what would be the homotopy between $g \circ f$ and $Id_X$?  I don't understand how to construct it.  What is the function $Q: X \times I \rightarrow X$ such that $Q(x,0) = g \circ f(x)$ and $Q(x,1) = Id_X(x) = x$?

Comment: Ok let's take $[0,1]$ and $\{0\}$. So ${\rm id}_X := x\mapsto x$ and you want to show that $f:x\mapsto 0$ is homotopic to ${\rm id}_X$. Such an homotopy is given by $H(t,x) = tx$.

Comment: I understand how to show that the unit interval is a retract, but I don't understand how to construct the full description of a homotopy between $g \circ f $ and $Id_X$.

Comment: I've just given to you. And btw, a retract (by deformation) is always a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: So supposing $H : X \times I \rightarrow X$ and $H(x,0) = 0$ ($0$ being the center of $X$?), then $H(x,0) = g \circ f(x) = 0$.  But if $x$ is in one of the upper prongs that's mapped back into itself, then how can $g \circ f(x) = 0$?

Comment: I was taking $X=[0,1]$ and $Y=\{0\}$. If you take back your case, just set $H$ constant equal to identity on the rest of $X$ (i.e. on $Y$).

Comment: If you could explain in detail the exact function $H : X \times I \rightarrow X$ such that $X$ is the letter "X" and $H(x,0) = g \circ f(x)$ and $H(x,1) = Id_X$ it would be really helpful.  I'm self learning this so as detailed an explanation as possible of the function would be best for helping me understand this.